# Julia in slurm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, julia, cluster-computing, slurm

did not find this question here - I am trying to use julia on slurm cluster, basically i am setting up this slurm cluster on my local machine: https://github.com/giovtorres/slurm-docker-cluster.git, the "cluster" is working and i can submit jobs but I cannot figure out how to get Julia into cluster (should I install it thru docker file + yaml - docker compose), or could i use locally installed Julia somehow thru Env. modules (or Lmod), any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

I am trying to use julia on slurm cluster on windows machine

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in a slurm environment. Although I run Linux nodes rather than a group of dockers.

1. Install Julia on all nodes or install Julia on a shared folder such as lustre. If you share `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` make sure that all nodes having the same `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` have the same hardware
2. Enable passwordless ssh (this is how Julia cluster nodes communicate). Ideally each node in the cluster should be able to password-less `ssh` to all other nodes.
3. Use ClusterManagers to add workers to the main process. This is a code I was running on Cray, with folders changed to what I saw in the GitHub link you posted:

```
using ClusterManagers
addprocs_slurm(32,job_name="somename", account="some_account", time="01:00:00", exename="/data/julia/usr/bin/julia")
cd("/data")
```

Oroginally this has worked for me with a lustre installation folder, but I understand the library that you have uses `/data` folder. Of course Julia installation should be there.
Hope  this should work for start.

Comment: I have managed to install it on  ../data/ with wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.10/julia-1.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar zxvf julia-1.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz but the out job is: /var/spool/slurmd/job00006/slurm_script: line 6: module: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job00006/slurm_script: line 8: generate_pbs_nodefile: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job00006/slurm_script: line 9: julia: command not found
so not sure is julia actually installed?

Comment: You will need to provide a full path to the Julia executable (look at `exename` in my command). Perhaps adding to the PATH is also an option, but in this type of environments I have been always using rather the full path to the executable.